# Split String in to different SQL Server columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a string in a table that I need to split into different columns, this is my string;

```
"VEX_NAME=LILIAN BRIGHT||VEX_ID=3006030"
```

I would like to be split in the format below

```
  VEX_ID  |  VEX_NAME
  --------+----------------
  3006030 | LILIAN BRIGHT
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using - it will be relevant to this answer

Comment: Sql server 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substring()` & `charindex()` :

```
select substring(col, charindex('VEX_ID=', col) + 7, len(col)) as VEX_ID,
       substring(col, charindex('VEX_NAME=', col) + 9, 
                 charindex('||', col) - (charindex('VEX_NAME=', col) + 9 )) as VEX_NAME
from table t;
```

However, you can also use `APPLY` :

```
select substring(col, VEX_ID, len(col)) as VEX_ID,
       substring(col, VEX_NAME, pipe - VEX_NAME) as VEX_NAME
from table t cross apply 
    ( values (charindex('VEX_ID=', col) + 7, charindex('VEX_NAME=', col) + 9,  charindex('||', col))
    ) tt(VEX_ID, VEX_NAME, pipe);
```